# How to change the main images of the website?

Tags: hugo

I built locally a website with Hugo Apéro. The main image of this theme is `revoir.jpg`.

I want to substitute `revoir.jpg`, and possibly all the other default images, with my collection of images, let call them `A.jpg`, `B.jpg`, etc...

I found `revoir.jpg` in the folder `themes`, but even replacing `revoir.jpg` with the content of `A.jpg`, the local website will build `revoir.jpg` as main image.

I cannot find the link to `revoir.jpg` in `config.toml` nor in other files!

Comment: When you add a submodule in Git, you don't add the code of the submodule to the main repository, you only add information about the submodule that is added to the main repository. If you want to apply some changes to the theme, you have to make changes to the repo of your theme.  But in your case you just need to replace the images under `static/img` of your main repo with the same name and extension https://bwaycer.github.io/hugo_tutorial.hugo/themes/customizing/

Comment: This will change the main image on the R Studio Viewer, but not in the local host, nor in the netlify site. I think the only solution is to literally force a "custom" theme, even if I don't know very well the minimal requirements to perform this.

Comment: You basically need to repeat the same steps that you did previously, with the official theme but you would need to fork the theme into your Github account and link the git repository with the submodule command. I would still recommend to replace the theme's files in your working directory. In your case you probably need to change some settings in your config. There's an issue on [Github](https://github.com/hugo-apero/hugo-apero/issues/35) about the static folder. You could also check [this repo](https://github.com/rbind/apreshill) which is using Hugo Apero theme as an example.

Comment: The bug was due to differences between .jpg and .JPG, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I just needed to re-configure the param:`images:` in `\content\_index.md` to point towards a image in `\static\img`